# Values multiplication in Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to multiply Millions value with 10^6 and Thousand value with 10^3.

Can you please help me with the code since I am able to get the logic.

These all the unique values I have in column.  I am able to successfully separate the digits and the letter. Where the letter is `M`, I need to multiply them with 10^6 and for `K` I need to multiply with 10^3.

```
['110.5M', '77M', '118.5M', '72M', '102M', '93M', '67M', '80M',
       '51M', '68M', '76.5M', '44M', '60M', '63M', '89M', '83.5M', '78M',
       '58M', '53.5M', '51.5M', '38M', '64.5M', '27M', '81M', '69.5M',
       '59.5M', '62M', '73.5M', '59M', '46M', '43M', '36M', '57M', '24M',
       '30M', '4M', '64M', '30.5M', '62.5M', '52M', '45M', '34M', '46.5M',
       '61M', '41.5M', '44.5M', '56.5M', '53M', '50M', '55M', '36.5M',
       '45.5M', '43.5M', '35M', '39M', '18M', '21.5M', '50.5M', '54M',
       '40.5M', '37.5M', '28.5M', '37M', '32M', '26M', '33M', '38.5M',
       '35.5M', '9M', '15.5M', '22M', '14M', '42.5M', '31.5M', '42M',
       '25M', '29.5M', '31M', '24.5M', '27.5M', '29M', '16.5M', '23M',
       '19M', '4.2M', '40M', '41M', '28M', '22.5M', '34.5M', '32.5M',
       '20M', '26.5M', '25.5M', '21M', '13M', '17.5M', '11.5M', '8M',
       '6M', '19.5M', '6.5M', '20.5M', '23.5M', '18.5M', '17M', '12.5M',
       '15M', '13.5M', '4.8M', '3M', '1.5M', '16M', '10M', '11M', '7M',
       '14.5M', '5.5M', '10.5M', '4.5M', '12M', '0', '9.5M', '8.5M', '2M',
       '1.7M', '1M', '3.6M', '7.5M', '3.8M', '5M', '2.4M', '2.9M', '4.7M',
       '4.1M', '2.1M', '600K', '2.7M', '3.4M', '2.5M', '3.2M', '3.1M',
       '4.9M', '4.3M', '2.3M', '525K', '3.9M', '1.8M', '2.2M', '4.4M',
       '1.6M', '900K', '3.7M', '3.5M', '1.9M', '450K', '775K', '650K',
       '750K', '2.8M', '1.3M', '4.6M', '2.6M', '1.2M', '375K', '3.3M',
       '270K', '950K', '550K', '1.1M', '975K', '1.4M', '725K', '425K',
       '210K', '875K', '675K', '325K', '800K', '850K', '160K', '120K',
       '825K', '925K', '625K', '240K', '500K', '575K', '200K', '250K',
       '700K', '350K', '475K', '300K', '70K', '140K', '230K', '400K',
       '280K', '100K', '60K', '260K', '180K', '220K', '50K', '290K',
       '90K', '150K', '40K', '130K', '190K', '170K', '110K', '30K', '80K',
       '20K', '10K']
```

Please help me.

Thanks,
K R RAO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following code:

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'raw_val': ['110.5M', '77M', '118.5M', '72M', '102M', '93M', '67M', '80M',
       '51M', '68M', '76.5M', '44M', '60M', '63M', '89M', '83.5M', '78M',
       '58M', '53.5M', '51.5M', '38M', '64.5M', '27M', '81M', '69.5M',
       '59.5M', '62M', '73.5M', '59M', '46M', '43M', '36M', '57M', '24M',
       '30M', '4M', '64M', '30.5M', '62.5M', '52M', '45M', '34M', '46.5M',
       '61M', '41.5M', '44.5M', '56.5M', '53M', '50M', '55M', '36.5M',
       '45.5M', '43.5M', '35M', '39M', '18M', '21.5M', '50.5M', '54M',
       '40.5M', '37.5M', '28.5M', '37M', '32M', '26M', '33M', '38.5M',
       '35.5M', '9M', '15.5M', '22M', '14M', '42.5M', '31.5M', '42M',
       '25M', '29.5M', '31M', '24.5M', '27.5M', '29M', '16.5M', '23M',
       '19M', '4.2M', '40M', '41M', '28M', '22.5M', '34.5M', '32.5M',
       '20M', '26.5M', '25.5M', '21M', '13M', '17.5M', '11.5M', '8M',
       '6M', '19.5M', '6.5M', '20.5M', '23.5M', '18.5M', '17M', '12.5M',
       '15M', '13.5M', '4.8M', '3M', '1.5M', '16M', '10M', '11M', '7M',
       '14.5M', '5.5M', '10.5M', '4.5M', '12M', '0', '9.5M', '8.5M', '2M',
       '1.7M', '1M', '3.6M', '7.5M', '3.8M', '5M', '2.4M', '2.9M', '4.7M',
       '4.1M', '2.1M', '600K', '2.7M', '3.4M', '2.5M', '3.2M', '3.1M',
       '4.9M', '4.3M', '2.3M', '525K', '3.9M', '1.8M', '2.2M', '4.4M',
       '1.6M', '900K', '3.7M', '3.5M', '1.9M', '450K', '775K', '650K',
       '750K', '2.8M', '1.3M', '4.6M', '2.6M', '1.2M', '375K', '3.3M',
       '270K', '950K', '550K', '1.1M', '975K', '1.4M', '725K', '425K',
       '210K', '875K', '675K', '325K', '800K', '850K', '160K', '120K',
       '825K', '925K', '625K', '240K', '500K', '575K', '200K', '250K',
       '700K', '350K', '475K', '300K', '70K', '140K', '230K', '400K',
       '280K', '100K', '60K', '260K', '180K', '220K', '50K', '290K',
       '90K', '150K', '40K', '130K', '190K', '170K', '110K', '30K', '80K',
       '20K', '10K']})

# get the numeric component from the string column
df['val'] = df['raw_val'].str.split('K|M').str[0].astype(float)

# get the multiplier, ie. K or M
df['multiplier'] = df['raw_val'].str[-1]

# multiply it accordingly to the multiplier, ie. 1000 for K or 1000000 for M
df['result'] = np.where(df['multiplier'] == 'K', df['val'] * 1000, df['val'] * 1000000)
```

Output

```
    raw_val     val multiplier        result
0    110.5M 110.500          M 110500000.000
1       77M  77.000          M  77000000.000
2    118.5M 118.500          M 118500000.000
3       72M  72.000          M  72000000.000
4      102M 102.000          M 102000000.000
5       93M  93.000          M  93000000.000
6       67M  67.000          M  67000000.000
7       80M  80.000          M  80000000.000
8       51M  51.000          M  51000000.000
9       68M  68.000          M  68000000.000
10    76.5M  76.500          M  76500000.000
11      44M  44.000          M  44000000.000
12      60M  60.000          M  60000000.000
13      63M  63.000          M  63000000.000
14      89M  89.000          M  89000000.000
15    83.5M  83.500          M  83500000.000
16      78M  78.000          M  78000000.000
17      58M  58.000          M  58000000.000
18    53.5M  53.500          M  53500000.000
19    51.5M  51.500          M  51500000.000
20      38M  38.000          M  38000000.000
21    64.5...
```

Comment: Thanks very much and this works perfectly fine for me

Comment: Good to know! Would appreciate if you could accept it as an answer

Comment: How can i do this?

Comment: next to my answer above, there should be a checklist icon on the left hand side, all you need to do is to click on the check box. here's the document on how to do it if you would like to get more details https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Done Thanks very much